# Visual Studio - ASP.NET MVC 5 - Default Azure AD Authentication Project and Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the default Visual Studio template for AAD within an ASP.NET MVC Project.. I am fairly new to integrating ASP apps with Azure, and from what I can tell the default project template uses OWIN/ADAL to authenticate users with AAD.

Is there a way to get an access token for ***Microsoft Graph API*** not to be confused with the ***Azure AD Graph API***, for which I am able to successfully grab an access token (there are minor differences in what AAD Graph returns for each user vs Microsoft Graph (for example, the users picture in O365 does not sync with Azure AD)..

I have read plenty of articles and tested many of things (including example projects from the Microsoft Open Source Team). These examples seem to create some sort of a Token Storage class in order to grab the Msft Graph access token - my main concern is around the fact that their Startup.cs/Startup.Auth.cs files look different than the default template.. why is this?

I am happy to do my own research/testing/etc.. just hoping for someone to help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get an access token for Microsoft Graph API not to
>   be confused with the Azure AD Graph API

Not directly identified. If you want to operate a user, most time we will use [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-developers-guide) in the past. But we will use the Microsoft [Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) API in the future. It depends on your requirement. In the project, you can check your references, no need to add both library.

> my main concern is around the fact that
>   their Startup.cs/Startup.Auth.cs files look different than the default
>   template.. why is this?

It should be have a small team which is responsible for the template. Due to docs team and template team is not the same team in the most time, so they are not synchronized. If have demo project, just use it directly. Docs is just for reference. Templates are not synchronized with the latest features too.

Comment: I have to get the users profile picture (user.ThumbnailPhoto) - but picture does not sync from O365 to Azure, meaning I can get all sorts of user info using Azure AD Graph API outside of the thumbnailPhoto. When a user sets their profile picture in O365 it does not sync to Azure. I need their profile picture - Microsoft Graph allows you to hook into O365..

Why do they make everything so difficult?!! All I want to do is use the Graph API as the existing user - how on earth do I get a Graph API access token from within my app!?!? I'm already using AAD auth.